# Adding JPanels to the JApplet with a null layout

Tags: java, swing

I want to add 4 JPanels to the JApplet I have, and I give to each one of them a different color.  But none of the colors are shown - I mean I can’t see the output. No colors at all.  The following code is in the `init()` method.

```
  this.setSize(1400, 780);
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  this.setLayout(null) ; 

      setLayout(null) ; 

  Panel1 = new JPanel() ;
  Panel2 = new JPanel () ; 
  Panel3 = new JPanel() ; 
  Panel4 = new JPanel() ; 

  Label1 = new JLabel ("Label1") ; 
  Label2 = new JLabel ("Label2") ; 
  Label3 = new JLabel ("Label3") ; 
  Label4 = new JLabel ("Label4") ; 

  Panel1.add(Label1) ; 
  Panel2.add(Label2) ; 
  Panel3.add(Label3) ; 
  Panel4.add(Label4) ; 

  // Panel 1 "About Me"
  Panel1.setSize(140,390) ; 
  Panel1.setLocation(0,0) ; 
  Panel1.setBackground(Color.red) ; 
  Panel1.setVisible(true) ; 
  this.add(Panel1) ; 

  // Panel 2 "MyHoppies" 
  Panel2.setSize(140,390) ; 
  Panel2.setLocation(0,700) ; 
  Panel2.setBackground(Color.yellow) ;
  this.add(Panel2) ; 

  // Panel 3 "Photo Gallery"
  Panel3.setSize(140,390) ; 
  Panel3.setLocation(390,0) ; 
  Panel3.setBackground(Color.black) ;
  this.add(Panel3) ;

  // Panel 4 "Happey face" 
  Panel4.setSize(140,390) ;
  Panel4.setLocation(390,700) ; 
  Panel4.setBackground(Color.pink) ; 
  this.add(Panel4) ;
```

Comment: Maybe because you keep applying `setBackground` (and `setLocation`) to Panel1?

Comment: @assylias consider posting this as an answer

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Apparently was a typo.

Comment: 1) `this.setSize(1400, 780);` Don't set the size of the frame, don't extend frame - just use an instance. 2) `this.setVisible(true);` Don't do that till after components are added and `pack()` is called.  3) `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` Will bomb out if this is called from an applet - even a trusted applet should not explicitly close the VM 4) `this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` Use `setLocationByPlaftform(true)` 5) `this.setLayout(null) ;` See mKorbel's answer. 6) `setLayout(null) ;`  Yes, the JRE heard you the *first* time you wrote that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can you tell me what the alternative is to `3)`? I sometimes refer to a WindowListener (if I want to save some stuff before closing the application), but in there, I also call `System.exit(0);`.

Comment: @brimborium  `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is the short answer to that.  After the custom action is completed, call `frame.dispose()` and the VM should exit of its own accord.  If it fails to exit, either the applet is still loaded, or there is another non-daemon thread running.  For more details, well.. this is a Q&A Site. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `this.setVisible(true)` must be last code line in the GUI constructor
- use [Using Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) correctly then `Panel1` should be `panel1` e.i.
- don't extends `JFrame` or `JApplet`, create that as local variable with the same way as for `Panel1`
- don't use `NullLayout`, use proper `LayoutManager` instead, in this case `GridLayout` probably, otherwise `JFrames` contents isn't resiziable with `JFrame`

[image]

code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorongPanels {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("ColorongPanels");
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label1");
    private JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label2");
    private JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Label3");
    private JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Label4");

    public ColorongPanels() {
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(label2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel3.add(label3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel4.setBackground(Color.pink);
        panel4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel4.add(label4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.add(panel2);
        frame.add(panel3);
        frame.add(panel4);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ColorongPanels();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @brimborium because you should not extend a class if you do not extends its functionality.

Comment: *"don't extends `JFrame` or `JApplet`"* Agree with frame, but try making an applet without extending `Applet` or `JApplet`  ;)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: You're completely right, thanks. I thought you meant that generally. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should do this: 
`panelx.setOpaque(true)` and it should work

Comment: Thanks, I see some rectangular with the colors but they are not filling the space it suppose to do.  I want to divide the window into four panels and each panel with different color.  the size of the window as I specified it is ( 1400 , 700 ) then each panel should have the size (400 , 390) widht and hight in order

Comment: Could you please update your code, so I can have a better idea?

Comment: @user1413188:If you don't need the panels for something else, you can just create one JPanel/JLabel, overwrite the `public void paintComponents(Graphics g)` method to draw whatever you want on it. It is usually not a good idea to use Layout for drawing. Unless you want to fill the JPanels with Components and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

First: You need to `JPanel.setOpaque(true)` the panels in order to see the background colors.

Second: The background color property has different effects on different platforms. For instance: If you set the background of a JButton, you will see the button colored in Win7, but not in WinXP (not sure, how it is under other operating systems). That is at least my experience...